# Using "Uno", "Un", and "Una" and a generalization of any number with a units digit of one

Tags: traducción, gramática, números

To start of, let me clarify what I "know" about "*uno*", "*un*", and "*una*":

- *Uno* is used when the object is not mentioned.
- *Un* is when the object is mentioned.
- *Una* is the feminine form of "*Un*".

(Again, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

With that said, how would these phrases be translated in Spanish. More importantly if we have a phrase where the amount is a two digit number or higher- except eleven- ending with 1 (i.e. 21, 41, 101), would the word "*uno*" change in certain conditions?

Phrases in question:

- "En julio hay treinta y un días." translates to ".... thirty-one days."
- "Francisco tiene veinte y un años." translates to "... 21 years" (I especially have trouble convincing myself that this is the correct way even though I hear it as "....y uno años."
- "Las frutas cuestan cincuenta y un centavos" translates to "....fifty-one cents" (Again, hard to believe, so please clarify).

Comment: The "diccionario panhispánico de dudas" (doubts dictionary) from the Spanish Royal Accademy (RAE) has normally all the rules with really useful examples: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=uno

Answer (score 8):

Your examples are correctly translated. There is a rule to use 'un' when it is used as an adjective compound from one or more words and that precedes masculine nouns.

```
Veintiún libros.
Treinta y un lápices.
```

But not when used with feminine nouns.

```
Veintiuna sillas.
```

Nor with prepositions

```
Veintiuno por ciento.
```

You can see the explanation here: http://www.rae.es/consultas/veintiuna-personas-veintiuno-por-ciento

Comment: Good answer +1. You can add this link for more examples http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=cardinales&lema=cardinales