# Why do we say "treinta y un días" instead of "treinta y unos días"?

Tags: número-gramatical

I learned about apocopation in Spanish, but the online sources I have seen only say that uno is shortened to un when it precedes a singular masculine noun, but días is plural, so why is it still "treinta y un días," "cincuenta y un días," etc.? Am I missing something?

I saw this related question ([Using "Uno", "Un", and "Una" and a generalization of any number with a units digit of one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/using-uno-un-and-una-and-a-generalization-of-any-number-with-a-units-dig)), but I'm still confused because I thought we'd use unos instead of un before plural masculine nouns.

I'd greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: This site: http://www.hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Numerales%20apocopados.htm might help to clarify.

Comment: It does help, thank you! Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers, when they are adjectives, remain invariable in the singular, even if they refer to plural nouns.

The following is not correct, even though the general grammar rule requires it:

> doses días (wrong)
> nueves días (wrong)

Instead, this is correct:

> dos días (right)
> nueve días (right)

Therefore, ***31 days*** is said ***treinta y un días***, since it is derived from ***treinta y uno***, not from ***treinta y unos***.

Comment: un día is correct. Only the other two are not. You might want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta más precisa sería que "**treinta y un días**" es la forma correcta debido a que la palabra "días" es un sustantivo masculino plural, y el numeral "*treinta y uno*" es utilizado para referirse a 31 unidades de algo, en este caso "*días*"

Aunque "*uno*" es un numeral singular, cuando se utiliza en conjunto con "treinta" para formar "*treinta y uno*", se refiere a una cantidad en plural, no en singular (*En el caso de "treinta y un días", "uno", se refiere a una cantidad en singular y, al agregar la palabra "días" la frase se convierte en un sustantivo masculino plural que indica una cantidad de días*). Por lo tanto, la forma correcta es "**treinta un días**", y no "*treinta y unos días*".

Comment: Diego, tu respuesta me parece confusa. ¿Cómo es una "cantidad en singular"? "Treinta y uno", salvo que se refiera a un porcentaje, siempre presupone pluralidad, aunque no esté explícito el sustantivo en plural: ¿Cuántos alumnos vinieron? / Treinta y uno (= treinta y un alumnos)

Comment: @Gustavson Hola, espero que estés bien. Gracias por señalar el error y lamento la confusión. Ya lo he cambiado, intentando que no haya tanta confusión. Saludos.